# Hide imagecell onlick and reveal the cells behind it

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have a row of cells that I want to appear like this upon page load

[image]

and once the user clicks 'health check', I want this to show

[image]

All the data that is hidden in the first picture is already loaded and ready to be shown, so the picture wouldn't require running any functions outside of reloading/revealing the table row. I'm not sure if this can be done in the javascript or if it would require a __dopostback to the codebehind, I'm open to anything that might work

Comment: A sample jsfiddle with some html will be much of a help in order to give a solution. It's **impossible** to know what do you mean by "All the data that is hidden in the first picture is already loaded and ready to be shown" Loaded where? how do get it?

Comment: Have you seen my answer? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use hidden cells with the values and toggle the visibility after click the `colspan` cell with the link.

Check this example below:

***HTML:***

```
<table id="tableExample" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Port</th>
    <th>KeyManager</th>
    <th>x</th>
    <th>y</th>
    <th>z</th>
    <th>w</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>DSW1...</td>
    <td>8445</td>

    <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;"><a class="health-check-button" href="#">health check</a></td>
    <td class="health-check-cell" style="display: none;">2</td>
    <td class="health-check-cell" style="display: none;">OK</td>
    <td class="health-check-cell" style="display: none;">3</td>
    <td class="health-check-cell" style="display: none;">OK</td>
    <td class="health-check-cell" style="display: none;">5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>DSW2...</td>
    <td>1000</td>

    <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;"><a class="health-check-button" href="#">health check</a></td>
    <td class="health-check-cell" style="display: none;">1</td>
    <td class="health-check-cell" style="display: none;">NOK</td>
    <td class="health-check-cell" style="display: none;">A</td>
    <td class="health-check-cell" style="display: none;">OK</td>
    <td class="health-check-cell" style="display: none;">X</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

***JavaScript:***

```
$(function(){
  $("#tableExample").on("click", ".health-check-button", function(e){
    var elem = e.target;
    $(elem).closest("td").css("display", "none");
    $(elem).closest("tr").children(".health-check-cell").css("display", "table-cell");
  });
});
```

***Plunker:***
https://plnkr.co/edit/0m9hFU2QWIq9ey12FqqG